# Import python modules to a Flask header file with jinja

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2, macos-catalina

Say I have this `header.html` file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{ random.randrange(0, 5) }}
    {% block body %}
        
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

and this `main.html` file which extends it:

```html
{% extends "header.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <p>Hello</p>
{% endblock %}
```

and this `main.py` file:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
import random

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template("main.html")

app.run()
```

Currently when I run this and go to the website it shows a `500 Internal Server Error` and I get this error in my python console:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'random' is undefined
```

How could I be able to somehow 'import' the random library into the header.html template?

I am running

Comment: I think you want `{{ range(5) |random }}`

Comment: @GAEfan Thanks, that works but is there any way I could do this with other libraries? I tried with os.listdir() and got `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'os'`

Comment: I think that error message is self-explanatory.  You can study the available filters at:  https://ansible-docs.readthedocs.io/zh/stable-2.0/rst/playbooks_filters.html  And know that you can't simply pass whatever python you want into the templating system.  Jinja2 and Python are not interchangeable.

Comment: @GAEfan I read that and it seems that a filter is not what I'm looking for. Is there a way I could use `render_template()` to send a list to the header file? All the ways I have found involve the file being displayed directly and not being extended from another file.

Comment: Yes, that is available out of the box.  Have you tried it?  I would have to see your code, but perhaps you are trying to access something outside its scope.  Here are details on scoping within blocks:  https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#block-nesting-and-scope

Comment: @GAEfan I decided that your other answer would work for what I wanted, but I will look into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jinja doesn't recognize `random`. That is python which has to be imported, therefore not jinja built-in.  Jinja has a built-in random filter:

```
{{ range(5)|random }}
```

**Update** for second part of question:

You can create your own filters using python.  Example (using Flask):

```
@app.template_filter('datetimeformat')
def datetimeformat(value, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"):
    return value.strftime(format)


{{ the_date|datetimeformat("%Y-%m-%d") }}
```

Comment: Is there a way I could import libraries into a flask template? I would like to do this with other libraries also not just random.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can use decorator `app.context_processor` to achieve that:

```
import os
import random


@app.context_processor
def handle_context():
    '''Inject object into jinja2 templates.'''
    return dict(os=os, random=random)
```

Then you can use `os, random` in your each template without input them in your view function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{{ random.randint(0,10) }}<br>
{{ os.path.abspath('') }}
</body>
</html>
```

You would get something like this:

```
6
F:\Python\MyProject
```